# To validate input to be only numbers with a limit of min and max 0-10000 using ng-pattern(new to angular)?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have two input fields to be of type numeric which allows a range of min value 0 and maximum value 10000.how would i make both the fields to allow numbers between max and minimum values no values beyond that.

I have tried with the following code please review and help

```
<div class='panel'>
    <span>Min: $&nbsp;</span>
    <input id="text-input-1" class="width" type="number" placeholder="USD " ng-model="vm.min" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/">
    <span>Max: $&nbsp;</span>
    <input id="text-input-1" class="width" type="number" placeholder="USD " ng-model="vm.max" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/">
</div>
```

But,As per my question i want in the user input fields only not to allow the values beyond my range.rather displaying messages

Comment: min & max attributes of type number should be enough .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use min and max attributes of `<input type="number"/>` and check validity of the field.

```
  <input id="text-input-1" min="0" max="10000" class="width" type="number" placeholder="USD" ng-model="vm.min">
```

or you can use ng-change to force min and max value by updating value if it is greater/smaller than min and max value, but I think first approach is better.

html

```
<input id="text-input-1" type="number" ng-model="value" ng-change="setConstraints(value)">
```

js

```
  $scope.setConstraints = function(value){
    if(value > 10000){
      $scope.value = 10000;
    }

    if(value < 0){
      $scope.value = 0;
    }
  }
```

**[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/gDA4AwMRFknSujLjapop?p=preview)**

Comment: thank you!...but i need in user input field only it should allow me to enter any value beyond 10000...i tried with min and max attributes they allow to do

Comment: @HKI345 updated answer and added a demo for you.

Comment: a quick question..can't we do it by REGEX anf ng-pattern?

Comment: ng-pattern also just checks the validity of input like min and max, it does not prevent user from inputing higher or lower values.